# Why is csrss.exe and ccsvchst.exe thrashing my hard drive for up to 45 minutes at a time?

Tags: symantec, csrss.exe

As of the past couple months, I have been the victim of serious hard drive thrashing from csrss.exe and ccsvchst.exe.  Together, these two processes completely commandeer my PC, making it practically impossible to do anything until they're done.

Is there a way to actually take control of my own computer?  Can't I put these processes on a low-priority tier or force them to require my approval before they attempt to access my drive for reads and/or writes?

Before I uninstall Symantec (ccsvchst) and try out Microst Security Essentials, I want to at least attempt to reign in these two processes.  There is no reason why they need to access my drive to the point where I cannot use my computer.

**Edit:**  I will add that there are a ton of threads on the internet with people complaining about this issue, especially from ccsvchst.exe.  However, as usual, the discussion threads are pages long each and consist of nothing but different people joining the thread with *This is happening to me, too.  Any solution yet?*.  I am hoping experts of SE have what it takes to actually address this issue.

Comment: I recall this happening to me when I had Norton installed, and I believe it automatically defragments or "optimizes" your hard drive. http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-360/I-can-t-stop-defrag-from-running/td-p/241367

Comment: I personally don't have much faith in Norton (though MSSE has really fallen from grace over the last 2 years), but you can likely adjust its on-access or active scan parameters to prevent it from doing much while you are using the box. That said, I too have had to abandon security platforms due to incompatibilities with other standalone security software or performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

Recently my server was having trouble launching JBOSS.  The problem turned out to be ccsvchst.exe, which had suddenly begun consuming over 50% available cpu.

This occurred after I created several large .zip files, which according to the thread below can incite a frenzy of activity in Symantec real-time scanning engine:

http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/what-does-ccsvchstexe32-do-symantec

The problem went away after I killed ccsvchst.exe via Taskmanager.