# ccsvchst, can it be shut down safely through Task Manager?

Tags: memory, cpu-usage, norton-antivirus

I've been experiencing issues with ccsvchst hogging both HDD and CPU resources on my notebook. The HDD light is steady CPU usage is high and the SYSTEM version just seems to keep growing in memory size. This is an older 32 bit system so I do not have a lot of memory overhead which is why everything pretty much comes to a screeching to a halt until it is finished.

I saw one answer which suggested just going into Task Manager and shutting down the process there, but is that really safe to do?

Answer (score 2):

Don't just stop the service (it may not even let you anyway, since it's probably protected from being stopped (by malware)).

It's Norton's anti-virus or 360 or something, so yo should be able to (temporarily) disable it via the program's UI.

Norton (especially older versions) are notoriously resource hungry.  My advise would be to uninstall Norton (which is what that service is from) and replace it with a more current, and lighter-weight protection solution.

Related SU question: [Why is csrss.exe and ccsvchst.exe thrashing my hard drive for up to 45 minutes at a time?](https://superuser.com/questions/608155/why-is-csrss-exe-and-ccsvchst-exe-thrashing-my-hard-drive-for-up-to-45-minutes-a)

Comment: ...it is bundled with my ISP service so I cannot just replace it.  Also I use the notebook as my primary online system since my other system (which is what I am sending from now) is a dedicated CG workstation that I usually only go online with to get updates for my software.

Comment: There are also not a lot of other good AV solutions. In my book MSSE is like a screen door on a space station and McAfee has some serious issues as well (the only time my system ever was infected was when I was running McAfee).

Comment: Ok a couple points:  The first thing I recommend is to simply disable the AV protect via the UI, did you try that?  Your ISP can't dictate to you which AV package you use (if any), so the idea that you somehow can't remove/replace it is not true.  I'm not here to debate which AV packages are good/bad, you can decide that for yourself.  If you're worried about going unprotected, then you definitely don't want to disable that service.

Comment: @BCShelby - The Norton package you have installed isn't required, if `ccsvchst` is a resource hog, get rid of the Norton package.